# FBO and Render to renderbuffer

Tags: opengl

Hi I am trying to use the Framebuffer object extension for offscreen rendering following the notes and example on :
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html

I am having a problem how to display the contents i have drawn on the FBO to the window!  I am getting only a fully black screen!

Also are textures preferable?  I have found that renderbuffers are better in performance is that so?

Can anyone help me with this pls?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GLUT/glut.h>   


void drawfunc();
void init(int argc, char** argv);
void initialise_FBO_toRenderBuf();
void onExit();

GLuint renderbufID;
GLuint bufferID;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    init(argc,argv);
    initialise_FBO_toRenderBuf();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawfunc);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void init(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //initialising window settings
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GL_RGBA8);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello Leanne mine");
    /*GLubyte* versiongl;
     versiongl = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
     printf("version is: %s\n",versiongl);
     */
    //initial background colour of the window
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //the coordinate system to be used
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -10.0, 1.0);


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

}

void initialise_FBO_toRenderBuf(void)
{


    //generate FBO name (bufferID) and create a buffer objct with the texture name (bufferID)
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &bufferID);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, bufferID);


    //generate renderbuffer name (renderbufID) and create a renderbuffer object with the renderbuffer name (renderbufID)
    glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &renderbufID);
    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, renderbufID);

    //Create data storage and establish the pixel format and dimensions of the renderbuffer image by calling the following function
    glRenderbufferStorageEXT (GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_RGBA8,250, 250);

    //attach the texture to the FBO
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, renderbufID);

    switch(glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT))
    {

        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT:    printf("The fbo is complete\n"); break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_EXT:    printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_EXT\n"); break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT_EXT:    printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT_EXT\n"); break;   
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS_EXT:    printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS_EXT\n"); break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_FORMATS_EXT:    printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_FORMATS_EXT\n"); break;
    }

}


void drawfunc()
{
    //use the FBO with name bufferID
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, bufferID);

    //clears the FBO to this color when glClear is called i.e it is the texture background color
    glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //drawing here
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);
    glVertex2f(0.25, 0.75);
    glVertex2f(0.75, 0.75);
    glVertex2f(0.75, 0.25);
    glEnd();


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.65);
    glVertex2f(0.65, 0.65);
    glVertex2f(0.65, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    GLvoid* pixels = malloc(250*250*4);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
    glReadPixels(0,0, 250,250, GL_RGBA8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);


    glDrawBuffer(0);
    //glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
    glRasterPos2d(0, 0);
    glDrawPixels(250, 250, GL_RGBA8,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);



    glFlush();

    onExit();
}

void onExit()
{
    //glDeleteTextures(1, &renderbufID);
    glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, &bufferID);
}
```

Comment: "Also are textures preferable?", preferable to what?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of at least some of the errors:

1. You call `glOrtho` without first having set the matrix mode to `GL_PROJECTION`, will probably "work" but the projection matrix will end up in the modelview matrix.
2. You should change the line `glDrawBuffer(0);` to `glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0)` to redirect the rendering to the window.
3. At the end of the draw function you delete the render target, what do you think will happen next time `drawfunc` is called?

After you've fixed these thing, put a breakpoint after `glDrawPixels` and check in your debugger that you got the correct data.

Comment: I did all the changes you suggested however i am still getting a black filled window!  i did a breakpoint just after the glReadPixels call and viewed the content in the memory browser, i was surprised to see that the contents here remained as they were before the call!  Do you have any idea why the glreadpixels is not changing the contentx at the area in memory pointed to by: pixels?

Comment: Change glClearColor to something other than black and see if the data from glReadPixels still comes out as all zero.